# In a heating curve, when it is plateau, where does all the energy go since the temperature does not get higher?

Tags: heat

So between the change of phases within the matter(solid liquid gas), the temperature reaches a plateau, no matter how much heat you add to it, it just stays the same. Where did all those energy go?

Answer (score 1):

You may have learnt at some point that a change of phase is **endothermic** (*i.e.* needs heat to happen). So, when you transition from a phase to another and keep adding heat, the temperature will remain the same, as ***all the heat you'll add will be used for the change of phase***. Hence, the temperature will remain the same until the transition is over (*i.e.* you gave your system enough heat for the transition to be complete), then will vary again.